# Meteor.js: Using Collection to store states of that collection

Tags: meteor

Happy Friday!

I have a somewhat newbie question for the community here and couldn't find a previous answer. I don't necessarily have enough code to create a package yet, but I wanted to store some helper methods on my collection that can be re-used everywhere and also re-use the "Words" collection namespace. I'm storing the client side in my lib folder. When I do this, am I doing anything weird to Mongo DB? From what I understand, Words initializes the Mongo collection but the actual variable is just a regular JS variable that you can add methods and properties to - the Mongo side of things can only be accessed via your .find(), .insert(), etc. methods. Is this accurate? And also generally, in general is this a good practice?

```
Words = new Mongo.Collection ('words');
Words.state = {};

Words.state.shuffle = function ( ) {
    return _.shuffle( Words.find().fetch() );
};
//find id of current set

Words.state.indexOf = function ( id ) {
    var i;
    var arr = Words.state.currentSet;
    for ( i = 0; i < arr.length ; i++ ) {
        if (arr[i]._id === id ) return i;
    }
};
```

Comment: i don't see anything wrong with that if that's what you want to do. However, I don't think is a question for stackoverflow. There is no right or wrong answer to your question. It's mostly opinion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**When I do this, am I doing anything weird to Mongo DB?**

No. Meteor communicates with mongo via a low-level mongodb driver, which is called only from the functions inherent to all [collections](https://docs.meteor.com/#/full/mongo_collection): `find`, `insert`, `remove`, `update`, etc. Therefore, you are free to modify the collection instance without fear as long as you don't replace any of the aforementioned functions.

**In general is this a good practice?**

This is a matter of opinion, but I think so. I like to add functions to both collection instances and to transformed documents. For example:

```js
Posts = new Mongo.Collection('posts');

Posts.fetchByAuthor = function(userId) {
  if (userId == null)
    userId = Meteor.userId();

  return Posts.find({authorId: userId}).fetch();
};
```

Now anywhere in your app, you can call `Posts.fetchByAuthor()` to get a list of posts by an author without needing to know how the collection data is stored under the hood.

In cases where you need extra functions on a document instance (rather than on the collection as a whole), I'd recommend using [collection helpers](https://github.com/dburles/meteor-collection-helpers). For example:

```js
Posts.helpers({
  author: function() {
    return Meteor.users.findOne(this.authorId);
  }
});
```

Now we can call `post.author()` anywhere in our app to get the author for a particular post. Again, we can invoke the function without needing to know the details of how an author is stored in the document.

Although these examples are simple, the technique of centralizing your model-layer logic is **extremely powerful** because it helps separate the concerns of your app. On larger projects, we have found this greatly simplifies our work, particularly when writing template code.

Recommended reading: [How to add a model layer to your app](http://dweldon.silvrback.com/models)

Answer (score 0):

Meteor community packages are best resource to learn how to extend Mongo Collections. One of my favorites is [collection-hooks](https://github.com/matb33/meteor-collection-hooks) but there are other like [aldeed:collection2](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-collection2) that force your insert and update operations to be compliance with a schema provided by the package [aldeed:simple-schema](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-simple-schema).

You should also google for Extending Objects in Javascript and you'll understand the package's code. Check jQuery and/or Underscore.js methods, you'll find relevant methods that make you life easier on this matter.